# Force Android App to have Jellybean Theme?

Tags: android, themes

I am making an Android app and was messing around with styles.  Instead of using the Material Light/Dark or other themes that I could find, is it possible to render the phone in Jellybean?  I would like the look and feel of Jellybean while keeping the functionality of Lollipop.  Does anyone know how to do this?

-- Ben

Comment: "I would like the look and feel of Jellybean" -- Jellybean was the name of an Android OS version, not a theme. If you mean "the default theme used with Jellybean", then that would be `Theme.Holo` and its sub-themes (e.g., `Theme.Holo.Light`, `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`). "while keeping the functionality of Lollipop" -- it is unclear what "the functionality of Lollipop" means.

Comment: I mean the look and feel that the Jellybean OS used, but still keeping the features of Lollipop.  (Toolbar, navigation, etc)

Comment: I am not aware that `Toolbar` will work with `Theme.Holo`, though I certainly have not tried it. I'm not sure what you mean by "navigation", as navigation with the action bar/toolbar was largely removed with Android 5.0.